# Cookie in PHP doesn't get set

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

```
error_reporting(-1); 
session_start(); 
$expire=time()+60*60;
setcookie('categories', $_SESSION['categories'], $expire);
```

This code should be setting up a Cookie, but it doesnt, in a IF cookie exists it tells me undefined index, I think the code is ok...

I've it in a page, até the secound line, after the

Anyone know's why it's not working? :s

UPDATE

Now I moved the code a little bit down... 
Still in the same situation, Undefined index

```
        $_COOKIE['newcoockievalu'] = json_encode($array);
    setcookie('newcoockievalu', json_encode($array), $expire);

    print "nocookie".($_COOKIE['newcoockievalu']);
```

This inside this IF

> `if (!isset($_COOKIE['newcoockievalu']))`

UPDATE

More strange.... It doesn't give any error, but it 'say' that the isset is allways false... but it prints the $_COOKIE['newcoockievalu'] ok....

Comment: What exactly is happening in which line?

Comment: I guess the undefined index is for `$_SESSION['categories']`

Comment: @RenePot No, it's for $_COOKIE['categories']

Comment: I define de SESSION above, so when the reload happens, the cookie get the categories, and its set

Comment: if ( $_COOKIE['categories']=='')

Comment: so what is in the `$_SESSION['categories']`. Have you checked it contains something?

Comment: Yes, because inside de IF, @ the end, I echo the $_SESSION['categories'] and it returns everything I need...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19085/discussion-between-nunong21-and-rene-pot)

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and its absolutely right. The second parameter must be string.

Please make sure that you set the cookie name categories from a session value which must be a string. Then in the next reload it will be there.. :)

Comment: I've noew changed it to another one @ the end of the if... only the unseted cookie again... gonna update

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must enable error reporting to `E_ALL` because you have no idea what's going wrong.

According to docs:

`setcookie()`

> If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail
>   and return FALSE. If setcookie() successfully runs, it will return
>   TRUE. This does not indicate whether the user accepted the cookie.

Right. It doesn't. So that you should check whether browser can accept the cookies.
Well, you can check property `cookieEnabled` of `navigator` object before you deal with cookies. For instance,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 if ( ! navigator.cookieEnabled ){
   //Cookies disabled
   //Do something like redirect to error page...
 }

</script>



<?php

// After you fix the problem, set this one to 0
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

function _setcookie($override = false){

  $key ='categories';
  $val = $_SESSION['categories']; 

  $expire=time()+60*60;

  //Did the one set before?
  if ( isset($_COOKIE[$key]) ){

     if ( $override ){
        //setcookie again here
     }

  } else {

      //Cookie wasn't defined so we'll do define:
      return setcookie($key, $value, $expire);
  }

}


function _getcookie($key){ 
  if ( isset($_COOKIE[$key]) ){
    return $_COOKIE[$key];
  }
  return null;
}


//Will set cookie if it doesn't not exists
_setcookie();

//Should print that key
print getcookie('categories');

?>
```

Comment: 1.  Yes I have E_ALL, and it doesn't show any error 2. I thought That , so that's why I changed the name to newcoockievalu. 3. It echo's well once it runs, but it doesnt save... 4. I have the same code as another page I made, and there it worked...

Comment: `setcookie()` merely sends HTTP headers just like `JavaScript` does to set key => value pair cookies. This also means that the cookies will be available in 1-1.5 sec (~at next HTTP request)

Comment: why the same code has worked on the same page? Well, this is because `setcookie()` "has done its own job" correctly. (on that script)

Comment: No, it worked on other page, with another name etc...  It just seems to not save this one... :s

Answer (score 0):

`$_COOKIE` will only be populated after the next request, not in the current request.

Comment: Yes, i reloaded the page... Yet, nothing :s